# Syntax for file and process exclusions in Forefront Endpoint Protection?

Tags: sccm, microsoft-forefront, system-center, microsoft-forefront-2010, sccm-2012

I can't seem to find an official and up-to-date documentation on how to set up file and process exclusions in Forefront Endpoint Protection 2012.

For file types, which of these will work? Are they the same?

- ext
- .ext
- *.ext

What about wildcards?

- .e?t
- .e*
- .*t

For file paths, which wildcards are allowed and how do they work?

- C:\path*
- C:\path\s*e
- C:\path\somef?le
- C:\*\somefile
- C:\pa*\somefile
- C:\pa?h\somefile
- *\path
- *:\path

For processes, can wildcard be used when specifying the file name? Same syntax as file paths?

Also: I read in [this post](http://blogs.technet.com/b/clientsecurity/archive/2010/03/08/wildcards-in-path-exclusions.aspx) that, as of October 2009, Real Time Protection ignored wildcards; is this still true for the 2012 version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes they're allowed and supported (but not your last 2 examples, can't use it for a drive letter, see link updated in 2014: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2962341